# Why is there a Key Lookup in this execution plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-administration

Can someone help me with this?

Shown here is a part of an execution plan:

[image]

Tables joined are `[Mark_group]` and `#PossibleMarkSchemeGroupIds.`

I tried to modify the index `[Mark_group].[IDX_Mark_Group_Mark_Shell]` to avoid the `Key_Lookup` (which appears in blue)

See the below image, to get an idea about what the Key Lookup is doing

[image]

in `[mark_Group], Mark_group_ID` is the primary key.

I was planning to add the columns from the Key Lookup task to the `INCLUDE` part of the index. But I can't find any other columns, other than the primary column.

`[PK_Mark_Group]` is the `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED INDEX` index. In Seek Predicates also I can see ONLY the primary key column.

Any idea what this task is doing here?

Comment: You should post the complete SQL Query you are trying to run

Comment: Have a look at the output columns for that operator in the SSMS properties window,

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the index IDX_Mark_Group_Mark_Shell includes all the needed columns from the table Mark_Group.
SQL Server uses the Index IDX_Mark_Group_Mark_Shell but additional data is needed and key lookup is done.